# Sqlite in android studio 2.2

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am getting error in writing query get error at DESC in function getfood.Here is my exception.

**Exception:**

*beginning of crash*

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

      Process: com.app.caloriescounter.admin.caloriescounter, PID: 2759
                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
    ComponentInfo{com.app.caloriescounter.admin.caloriescounter/com.app.caloriesc
    ounter.admin.caloriescounter.Main2Activity}: 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **invalid LIMIT clauses: DESC** 
             at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                          at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                          at 
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                          at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                          at 
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                          at 
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid LIMIT clauses: DESC 
                          at 
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.buildQueryString(SQLiteQueryBuilde
    r.java:209)
                          at 
   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1160)
                          at 
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
                          at 
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1240)
                          at 
    data.Databasehandler.getfood(Databasehandler.java:86)
                          at 
com.app.caloriescounter.admin.caloriescounter.Main2Activity.refreshdata(Main2Activity.java:38)
                          at com.app.caloriescounter.admin.caloriescounter.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:32)
                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                          at 
    android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                          at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                          at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 

                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-
    wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                          at 
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                          at 
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                          at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
```

this is my **Source Code:** of `Databasehandler` class.

```
    package data;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    import model.Food;

    /**
     * Created by Admin on 9/10/2016.
     */
    public class Databasehandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private static final String LOGCAT = null;
        private final ArrayList<Food> foodArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        public Databasehandler(Context context) {
            super(context,Constsnts.databasename,null,Constsnts.databaseversion);
            Log.d(LOGCAT,"Database Created");
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    String Crete_Table="CREATE TABLE "+ Constsnts.food_table+" ( " + 
    Constsnts.KeyId +"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + Constsnts.food_name +"TEXT, "
            +Constsnts.foodcalories +"INT , "+Constsnts.datename +"LONG );";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(Crete_Table);
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+Constsnts.food_table);
        //new one
            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
        }
        //item all
        public int getTotalitem(){
            int totalitem=0;
            String query=" SELECT * FROM "+Constsnts.food_table;
            SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query,null);
            totalitem=cursor.getCount();
            cursor.close();
            return totalitem;
        }
    public  int Caloriesall(){
            int calories=0;
            String query="SELECT SUM ( "+Constsnts.foodcalories +")"+"FROM 
    "+Constsnts.food_table;
            SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query,null);
            if(cursor.moveToNext()){
                calories=cursor.getInt(0);
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            return  calories;
        }
        //deletefood
        public void deletefood(int id){
           SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete(Constsnts.food_table,Constsnts.KeyId+" =? ",new String[]
    {String.valueOf(id)});
            db.close();
        }
        //add food
        public void addfood(Food food){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put(Constsnts.food_name,food.getFoodname());
            values.put(Constsnts.foodcalories,food.getCaleries());
            values.put(Constsnts.datename,System.currentTimeMillis());
            db.insert(Constsnts.food_table,null,values);
            Log.v("Added food item","yess");
            db.close();
        }
        //get all food
        public ArrayList<Food> getfood(){
            foodArrayList.clear();
            SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor=db.query(Constsnts.food_table,new String[]
    {Constsnts.KeyId,Constsnts.databasename,
Constsnts.foodcalories,Constsnts.datename},null,null,null,null,Constsnts.datename," DESC ");
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    Food food=new Food();
    food.setFoodname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constsnts.food_name)));
    food.setCaleries(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constsnts.foodcalories)));
    food.setFoodid(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constsnts.KeyId)));
                    DateFormat dateFormat=DateFormat.getDateInstance();
                    String data=dateFormat.format(new 
    Date(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constsnts.datename))).getTime());
                    food.setRecorddate(data);
                    foodArrayList.add(food);
                }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }
    cursor.close();
            db.close();
            return foodArrayList;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format your question, since it's unacceptable AS IS. Also mind the **spaces** between the field names and their types. And also post your query (the one with the `LIMIT` and `DESC` keywords).

Comment: I will close current tab immediately on my browser after this comment :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cursor=db.query(...,Constsnts.datename," DESC ");
```

The DESC must be part of the ORDER BY clause. You have put it into the next parameter, which makes it end up in the LIMIT clause.

You have to put the column name and the DESC into the same parameter:

```
Cursor cursor=db.query(...,Constsnts.datename+" DESC");
```

Comment: E/SQLiteLog: (1) table foods_tbl has no column named name
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=apple calories=543 recorddate=1474784938989

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table foods_tbl has no column named name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO foods_tbl(name,calories,recorddate) VALUES (?,?,?)

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.app.caloriescounter.admin.caloriescounter, PID: 2599
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.caloriescounter.admin.caloriescounter/com.app.caloriescounter.admin.caloriescounter.Main2Activity}:

Comment: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, cals.db, calories, recorddate FROM foods_tbl ORDER BY recorddate DESC

Comment: at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
                      at data.Databasehandler.getfood(Databasehandler.java:86)
                      at com.app.caloriescounter.admin.caloriescounter.Main2Activity.refreshdata(Main2Activity.java:38)
                      at com.app.caloriescounter.admin.caloriescounter.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:32)

Comment: Your question has been answered. To ask another question, use the "Ask Question" button.